# How to use commands again without copy and pasting them?

Tags: python

I don't really know how to explain this exactly.. But I'm making a text adventure for learning the basics. Now I want to make a gold and money system, I am using def... things for different levels and such. but in every prompt I have to put in if the user types gold, or inv it shows the inventory and then go back to the def where it was.. which I find irritating to do every time. And I forget it too at some periods. I want to do it as default in the prompt. 
I have a def prompt(): that is this easy code:

```
def prompt():
    x = input('Type a command: ')
    return x
```

and if I put it there it just ends the code. I have to do this in every prompt:

```
def AlleenThuis():
    command = prompt()
    if command == '1':
        print()
    elif command == '2':
        print()
    elif command == '3':
        print()
    elif command == '4':
        print()
    elif command == 'geld': #Actions start here
        print('\n\tYou have ' + str(gold) + ' euro. RICH BOY BRO!.\n')
        print()
        return AlleenThuis()
    elif command == 'inv':
        if not inv:
            print("\n\tYou don't have any items..\n")
            return AlleenThuis()
        else:               #The else has to stay in this place because it's part of the 'if not inv:' guys.
            print('\n\t' + str(inv) + '\n')
            return AlleenThuis()
            #Actions end here
```

So if there's any way to just implement it so that I don't have to put it in again every time that would be awesome!
Thanks.

EDIT: It looks like you guys aren't understanding what I'm saying, so I have 2 images.
So.. 
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz9NK.png** (I can't post pictures yet =[ )

As you can see in this picture, I have included gold and inv.
But in **https://i.stack.imgur.com/84zKp.png** I have also done that, so I have coded that in the code again, that is what I Don't want!

I just want to have that in the code 1 time, and let the gold and inventory show all the time when the player enters the commands for them!

Comment: Your text is very confusing, but i think you're saying that all these ``elif``s are confusing... is that right?

Comment: No, I removed some parts of the code to make it shorter, I understand the _elif_'s and all. but I want to know how to display the gold, and the inventory I have, without needed to put it in every Input.. thing. Sorry if I'm not good at explaining.

Comment: You mean Python's interactive prompt? The one with ``>>>`` at the beginning?

Comment: @Stepepper as you can see, you have 4 different answers about 4 different things. Probably, you should be more specific to get the right answer? Nobody knows here about golds and inventories, only a bit about python, so be closer to programming than to quests, please.

Comment: I have edited the question, I find this very hard to explain since English isn't my first language. Sorry!

Comment: I edited my answer to provide an example (at the very bottom) for how to not repeat that code.  It's a good question!  However, I'd suggest taking a look at my entire answer and thinking about how to restructure what you're doing -- the code probably doesn't need to be that complicated.

Comment: I also added another answer that separates out just the very specific thing you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a more fundamental level, the object-oriented paradigm elegantly solves the problem of repetitive code like this:

```
global gold = 0
def cave():
    print "You are in a cave."
    print "You have %i gold." % gold
    direction = input()
    if direction = 'N':
        stream()
    elif direction == 'S':
        house()
    elif direction == 'W':
        mountain()
    elif direction == 'directions':
        print "You can go North, West, or South."
    else:
        print "You cannot go there."
def stream():
    print "A small stream flows out of the building and down a gully."
    print "You have %i gold." % gold
    direction = input()
    if direction == 'N':
        tree()
    elif direction == 'S':
        cave()
    elif direction == 'directions':
        print "You can go North or South."
    else:
        print "You cannot go there."

def main():
    cave()
```

by turning it into something like this:

```
class Location:
    map = { 'cave': {
              'description': 'You are in a cave.',
              'directions': { 'N': 'stream', 'S': 'house', 'W': 'mountain' } },
            'stream': {
              'description':
                'A small stream flows out the building and down a gully.',
              'directions': { 'N': 'tree', 'S': 'cave' } } #...
          }
    def __init__ (self):
        self.location = 'cave'
    def enter (self, direction):
        self.location = self.map[self.location]["directions"][direction]
        print self.map[self.location]["description"]
    def directions(self):
        return self.map[self.location]["directions"].keys()
    def readable(self, dirs):
        readable = { 'S': 'South', 'N': 'North', 'W': 'West', 'E': 'East' }
        return [readable[d] for d in dirs]

class Inventory:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.inventory = { 'gold': 0 }
    def query (self):
        print "You have %i gold." % self.inventory['gold']

def main:
    loc = Location()
    inv = Inventory()
    while True:
        directions = loc.directions()
        action = raw_input()
        if action in directions:
            loc.enter(action)
            inv.query()
        elif action == 'directions':
            where = loc.readable(directions)
            print "You can go " + ", ".join(where[:-1])\
                  + ", or " + where[-1]
        else:
            print "You cannot go there."
```

You will notice that the more modular code is also easier to extend.  For example, the inventory can now hold more things than gold, and it's easy to add new commands to query for weapons, potions, etc.  Furthermore, it somewhat separates the code from the data, making it less cumbersome and error-prone to add new locations and actions.

Next up, define `class Object` with subclasses for animate objects, objects you can pick up, immobile objects, etc; and populate the locations with instances of these.  Different subclasses can have different interactions defined, and inherit from more basic superclasses which implement fundamentals like `take`, `drop`, `kill`, etc.

What to map into objects is a broad topic, but a few simple guidelines would be to isolate and encapsulate unrelated code into their own classes, and make them as decoupled as possible (code implementing "location" should not need to know pretty much anything about code in "inventory", and vice versa).

Comment: While I think OO code structure is the right fix the this question, your code has some problems. You're using class variables, rather than instance variables, and your methods don't take a `self` parameter.

Comment: Feel free to fix it up; I felt as if I was going a bit overboard with this answer, and struggled for a bit to come up with a reasonably simple and self-contained example.  But it certainly ought to show a reasonably correct approach.

Comment: I fixed the remaining obvious bugs. I think a better design would be to have multiple `Location` instances, one for each actual location in the game, but it would be a bit more complicated to set that up (rather than having the single `map` dict specify everything).

Comment: I am seriously confused by this now. I understand much, but what is _init_`? Do you care to give explanation to all this?

Comment: This comment box is much too small for that. Seriously, google a Python OOP tutorial and/or post a separate follow-up question. Anyway, `__init__` is a function, or rather, a method that gets called when an object is instantiated, but none of this makes sense until you know what classes are and how to use them properly.

Comment: Now some six years later I would also make sure the `print()` and `input()` calls are in `main()` and that no other code does user interaction, or at the very least make sure the user interaction is near the code surface and separate from the actual logic inside the other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for this has some serious structural problems.  If I understand correctly, you're trying to accept repeated commands and execute some code to make them function the way you intend.

The problem is that your function to run the game is recursive, so every time you execute a command other than 1, 2, 3, or 4, you're calling your function again without returning from the first one.  Eventually, if you enter enough commands, you'll get an error saying that you're recursing too deeply and the game will error out.

What you want is something more like this:

```
def prompt():
    x = input('Type a command: ')
    return x

def ProcessAction(command):
    if command == '1':
        print()
    elif command == '2':
        print()
    elif command == '3':
        print()
    elif command == '4':
        print()
    elif command == 'geld': #Actions start here
        print('\n\tYou have ' + str(gold) + ' euro. RICH BOY BRO!.\n')
        print()
    elif command == 'inv':
        if not inv:
            print("\n\tYou don't have any items..\n")
    else:
        print('\n\t' + str(inv) + '\n')
    #Actions end here

curr_command = None
while curr_command not in ("1", "2", "3", "4"):
    curr_command = prompt()
    ProcessAction(curr_command)
```

What this will do is keep asking for new commands and processing them until one of the commands that exits the game is entered.

Edit:  From your comment below, it sounds like you're trying to figure out how to display gold and inventory every time a command is entered without requiring a special command to do it.  If this is what you're after, you can add print statements to the `while` loop above to ensure that it's printed before every prompt.  In that case, the while loop might look like:

```
while curr_command not in ("1", "2", "3", "4"):
    print('\n\tYou have ' + str(gold) + ' euro. RICH BOY BRO!.\n')
    if not inv:
        print("\n\tYou don't have any items..\n")
    else:
        print('\n\t' + str(inv) + '\n')
    curr_command = prompt()
    ProcessAction(curr_command)
```

Hope that gets closer to what you're after.

Edit 2:  Ok, after reading the full code for your game, I think you might want to consider reorganizing the entire thing.  Think about what you want the game to be: the player enters a series of commands and each command does two things, it changes the game's state and it prints out a response based on both the current state and the new state.

So, you should think about processing your commands with a loop like I described.  Then, fold all those different functions into ONE `ProcessAction(command)` function that figures out from the game's state (which you store in variables) what to print out and how to change the state.

If it's a game where you're going room to room, for example, you might keep a global variable `room` that defines where you are.  Your `ProcessAction` function then follows logic that says "If I'm in room A and the character types this thing then print out B and change room to C, and sets gold to 0."

To make this work well, you'll have to step back and think about the overall "story" of your game, how to store the state in various variables, and how to make your ONE `ProcessAction` function handle all the possible states and commands that can be issued.

Doing this puts you on the path of developing what's called a "state machine," where you have a simple, general function that looks at a data structure (probably some nested dicts) that you fill up with what each command does when your game is in each state and where to go next, as well as what to print out.

This Wikipedia article describes the concept of a state machine.  How you implement it in Python is up to you.  I can tell you that if you're careful you should be able to do this without repeating any code.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine

Another edit:  Answering a question you placed in the comments below, if you think you have to print out, for example, the value of a player's gold in multiple places, you can do something like this:

```
def print_gold(gold_value):
    print('\n\tYou have ' + str(gold_value) + ' euro. RICH BOY BRO!.\n')
    print()
```

then use `print_gold(gold)` in place of those print statements whenever you need to do that.  However, I think you may want to take a step back and think about rewriting the whole thing with some of the thoughts I've offered before you tackle that problem.

Comment: the else: in my command belongs to 'if not inv:'so I'll probably have to add another else, won't I? So.. how would this get into working exactly? And: http://pastebin.com/nTDLijqq this is my whole code. It's quite offensive but it's only for myself and some friends. I'll try out the code that you gave me. Thanks!

Comment: What I posted prints out "you don't have any items" if `inv` evaluates to false and otherwise prints out the string that contains the inventory.  I'm not sure what another `else` would do, but if you want to clarify, go for it and I'll try to keep up!  Just to be clear, an `else` that follows an `if` block should be indented to the same level to be evaluated correctly.

Comment: That's a little closer to what I'm after, yes. But I want to have the player enter the command gold or inv, but I have to code it in the prompt everytime. If you look at my script, you can see that I have put the gold and inventory thing in there multiple times, that's what I don't want, I just want it when you enter gold or inv it shows one of them. Without the need to put it in the code every time the user needs to type.

Comment: I have offered some additional thoughts that might deal with the problem you're trying to solve.  Using a state machine will require rethinking a lot of your existing code, but it's how almost all games like the one you're describing are implemented, and it's definitely the most economical way.

Answer (score 1):

My earlier answer is long and addresses a number of problems in the OP's code, but he's asking about one specific thing, so I thought I'd separate out that answer here.

If you have some code you'd like to repeat multiple times, you might be tempted to copy and paste it around in your code  In your case, that would be something like:

```
print('\n\tYou have ' + str(gold) + ' euro. RICH BOY BRO!.\n')
print()
```

Wrapping that in a function will allow you to execute that same code anytime you need to do that thing, without copying and pasting.  You're already defining functions, so you seem to have the concept down, but this wrapped in a function might look like:

```
def print_gold(gold_value):
    print('\n\tYou have ' + str(gold_value) + ' euro. RICH BOY BRO!.\n')
    print()
```

With this function defined, anytime you place `print_gold(gold)` in your code, it'll pass the value of `gold` into that function as the variable `gold_value` and print it out as you've specified.

So, if for some reason you had code that looked like this:

```
print('\n\tYou have ' + str(gold) + ' euro. RICH BOY BRO!.\n')
print()
print('\n\tYou have ' + str(gold) + ' euro. RICH BOY BRO!.\n')
print()
print('\n\tYou have ' + str(gold) + ' euro. RICH BOY BRO!.\n')
print()
```

you could turn this into:

```
def print_gold(gold_value):
    print('\n\tYou have ' + str(gold_value) + ' euro. RICH BOY BRO!.\n')
    print()

...  somewhere else in your code ...

print_gold(gold)
print_gold(gold)
print_gold(gold)
```

Those three lines are function calls, which tell Python to execute the function you've defined with `def`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the latest edit to your question, then you might want something like:

```
def get_gold_or_inv(command):
        if command == 'geld': #Actions start here
            print('\n\tYou have ' + str(gold) + ' euro. RICH BOY BRO!.\n')
            print()
        elif command == 'inv':
            if not inv:
                print("\n\tYou don't have any items..\n")
            else:
                print('\n\t' + str(inv) + '\n')

while True:
    command = prompt()
    if command == '1':
        print()
    elif command == '2':
        print()
    elif command == '3':
        print()
    elif command == '4':
        print()
    get_gold_or_inv(command)
```

Comment: Okay, seems like you guys are misunderstanding something with the _elif_'s. The _elif_'s are right! I just removed part of the elif 1 2 3 4 prompts. I meant how to display the gold and inventory every time, without needing to put it in the code everytime. For example I'm in the middle of the game and I want to check my gold It does this then:

enter a command: gold
You have 5000 gold (or something)
It displays the code! But I have to put it in that piece of code EVERYTIME to let it display. I want it to be a default input, so that I don't have to put it in everytime

Comment: I've updated my answer, basing on the latest edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say that you want this to run in an infinite loop until quit?
You can do that either by encapsulating the entire function block with a `while True:` or just by calling AlleenThuis() after the `if`s and `elif`s. I took the liberty to rewrite your implementation using the first option below.

```
def AlleenThuis():
    while True:
        command = prompt()
        if command == '1':
            print()
        elif command == '2':
            print()
        elif command == '3':
            print()
        elif command == '4':
            print()
        elif command == 'geld': #Actions start here
            print('\n\tYou have ' + str(gold) + ' euro. RICH BOY BRO!.\n')
            print()
        elif command == 'inv':
            if not inv:
                print("\n\tYou don't have any items..\n")
            else:
                print('\n\t' + str(inv) + '\n')
        else:
            print("Invalid command")
```

Hope I didn't misunderstand you.

**EDIT:**

```
def action(cmd):
    if cmd == 'geld':
        print('\n\tYou have ' + str(gold) + ' euro. RICH BOY BRO!.\n')
        print()
    elif cmd == 'inv':
        if not inv:
            print("\n\tYou don't have any items..\n")
        else:
            print('\n\t' + str(inv) + '\n')
    else:
        # If the command was not found
        return False
    # If the command was found and the else statement was not run.
    return True
```

Then just run this at the start of every scenario `if action(command): return ScenarioName()`.
Hope that helps!

Comment: Dude, after reading your responses to the other answers I think one thing is clear; we have no idea what you are talking about when you say "put it in every time". I hope you are not writing this in the Python interpreter itself...

Comment: I just now read your entire code, perhaps you should just do a function commands() that contain basic commands like `geld`, `inv` and `exit` then run it at the start of every "scenario" (if I now understand you correctly).

Comment: Yes! That's it! Can you also tell me how that goes into work?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are currently pasting something into this prompt everytime you want to run your Python program, and your question is about how to avoid that:

[image]

The answer to this problem is generally to save your program's code in a `whatever.py` file and run that file... either by doubleclick or through the terminal. The exact instructions depend on your operating system etc.

Comment: I don't think this is his problem, but if it is, you're awesome! :D