# Is it possible to have a user input two new answers for one variable and have it change each time asked?

Tags: python, python-2.7, adventure

```
elif direction == "kitchen".lower():
    print""
    print("• As you enter the kitchen you get blasted with heat. "+kitchen)            
    print""
    print("• "+lobby)
    print""
    direction=raw_input("• Where would you like to go next? ")
    if direction == "kitchen".lower():
        print""
        print("• As you enter the kitchen again the stove explodes and you die             in the fire.")
        print""
        print("• Game over.")
    else:
        print""
elif direction == "closet".lower():
    print""
    print("• As you step closer to the closet you can tell the door was      smashed down by something.")
    print""
```

Is it possible to change direction from "kitchen" to "closet" or do i need two variables? this is for a text adventure game trying to enter new rooms.

Comment: I suspect you meant to write `direction.lower()`.  The string `"kitchen"` is already lowercase.

Comment: Tangentially see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557616/how-to-use-commands-again-without-copy-and-pasting-them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what are you doing is correct. You can assign a new value to a variable anytime.